# How to web scrape through multiple pages with BeatuifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape multiple pages with beutifulsoup and I have successfully retrieved data for a single page. Now, I wonder how should I implement some loop to retrieve the data from through several pages.

The link to the web page is: https://www.diac.ca/directory/wpbdp_category/dealers-distributors/

Here's my code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get('https://www.diac.ca/directory/wpbdp_category/dealers-distributors/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

csv_file = open('scrape.csv', 'w')

csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['company', 'website'])

for i in soup.find_all('div', class_='wpbdp-listing'):
    company = i.find('div', class_='listing-title').a.text
    print(company)

    website = i.find('div', class_='wpbdp-field-business_website_address').span.a.text
    print(website)

    csv_writer.writerow([company, website])

csv_file.close()
```

I would really appreciate any feedback or insight. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is try to find link under tag with `class=next`. If the link exist, use it to load the next page. If the link doesn't exist, break the loop:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://www.diac.ca/directory/wpbdp_category/dealers-distributors/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

page = 1
while True:
    print('Page no. {}'.format(page))
    print('-' * 80)
    for i in soup.find_all('div', class_='wpbdp-listing'):
        company = i.find('div', class_='listing-title').a.text
        print(company)

        website = i.find('div', class_='wpbdp-field-business_website_address').span.a.text
        print(website)

    if soup.select_one('.next a[href]'):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(soup.select_one('.next a[href]')['href']).text, 'lxml')
        page += 1
    else:
        break
```

Prints:

```
Page no. 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AMD Medicom Inc.
http://www.medicom.ca
Clinical Research Dental Supplies & Services Inc.
http://www.clinicalresearchdental.com
Coltene Whaledent
http://www.coltene.com
CompuDent Systems Inc.
http://www.compudent.ca
DenPlus Inc.
http://www.denplus.com
Dental Canada Instrumentation
http://www.mydentalcanada.com
Dental Services Group of Toronto Inc.
http://www.dsgtoronto.com
Dental Wings Inc.
http://www.dentalwings.com
Dentsply Sirona Canada
http://www.dentsplysirona.ca
DiaDent Group International Inc.
http://www.diadent.com
Page no. 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DMG America LLC
http://www.dmg-america.com
Hager Worldwide, Inc.
http://www.hagerworldwide.com
Hansamed Ltd
http://www.hansamed.net
Henry Schein Canada
http://www.henryschein.com
Heraeus Kulzer LLC
http://www.heraeus-kulzer-us.com
Johnson & Johnson Inc.
http://www.jjnjcanada.com
K-Dental Inc.
http://www.k-dental.ca
Kerr Dental
http://www.kerrdental.com
Northern Surgical & Medical Supplies Ltd.
www.northernsurgical.com
Northern Surgical and Medical Supplies Ltd.
http://www.northernsurgical.com
Page no. 3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Patterson Dental/Dentaire Canada Inc.
http://www.pattersondental.ca
Procter & Gamble Oral Health
http://www.pg.com
Qwerty Dental Inc.
http://www.qwertydental.com
Sable Industries Inc.
http://www.sableindustriesinc.com
Septodont of Canada, Inc.
http://www.septodont.ca
Sure Dental Supplies of Canada Inc.
http://www.suredental.com
Swiss NF Metals Inc.
http://www.swissnf.com
The Aurum Group
http://www.aurumgroup.com
The Surgical Room Inc.
http://www.thesurgicalroom.ca
Unique Dental Supply Inc.
http://www.uniquedentalsupply.com
```

Comment: that's an elegant solution, however how should I adding these into csv? in which sequence should i consider adding csv commands?

Comment: @JasonTheMarketer Do the writing to `csv` like before...after `print(website)` call `csv_writer.writerow([company, website])` and it should work.

Comment: one last question please! what do i do if there's no 'website' property thus throwing an error like `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soup2.py", line 21, in <module>
    website = i.find('div', class_='wpbdp-field-business_website_address').a.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'`? Could I tell the system to simple skip instead of throwing an error and stopping the program?

Comment: @JasonTheMarketer One possibility is first do `website = i.find('div', class_='wpbdp-field-business_website_address')` and then check whether `website is None`. If it's None, assign to website some default value, e.g `'-'`. Else assign to website `website = website.a.text`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/osagce got it working! thanks sensei... btw what's the logic behind using `print('-' * 80)`?

Comment: @JasonTheMarketer Yes, `try .. except` is another possibility :) `print('-' * 80)` will just print 80 characters of `-`

Comment: @JasonTheMarketer For visual purposes to clearly separate pages

Answer (score 1):

The general process goes something like this:

```
# Make soup

links = [link.get('href') for link in soup.find_all('a')]  #These are the links you want to visit next


for link in links:
    requests.get(link)
    # Do whatever / make soup again
```

Something that also helps with this is `requests.Session()` which maintains cookies / headers etc.

```
session = requests.Session()

session.get(some_url)
```

Here is an example I just wrote that is a bit more involved to show the general flow of scraping:

```
def scrape_data(link):
    entries = soup.find_all('div', class_='data')
    return [entry.text for entry in entries]

def paginate(link):
     requests.get(link)
     links = soup.find_all('a', class_='nav')
     return [link.get('href') for link in links]

def main():
    data = [scrape_data(link) for link in paginate(starting_link)]
    # Export / process data here
```